# Different behaviours with ADJUST_RESIZE in BottomSheetDialogFragment

Tags: android, android-layout, android-softkeyboard, bottom-sheet

I'm trying to create a BottomSheetDialogFragment with a TextInputLayout inside. I'm setting this BottomSheet as adjustResize to prevent the keyboard cover the TextInputLayout. The thing is that I'm getting different behaviours with different android versions.

This is the layout:

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
    android:id="@+id/textInputLayout"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0">

    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="hint" />
</android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

This the BottomSheetDialogFragment:

```
public class TestFragment extends BottomSheetDialogFragment {

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    getDialog().getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_RESIZE);

    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_test, container, true);
}
```

}

This is the desired result:

[image]

And this is the result that I'm getting in some versions:

[image]

I'm getting the desired result with:

- Galaxy S6 with Android 7.0
- Emulator with <= Android 5.1

And no desired result with:

- Nexus 5 with Android 7.1.2 (LineageOS 14.1)
- Emulator with => Android 6.0

Does anyone know why this happen or how to solve it?

Thanks in advance!!!

Cheers.

Answer (score 2):

This issue wasted my 1 hour.Don't use `ADJUST_RESIZE`.

Simply **wrap your layout inside a `NestedScrollView`**.

Nothing More.Nothing less.Problem solved.

Here is the XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
            android:id="@+id/textInputLayout"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0">

            <android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:hint="hint" />
        </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

Here is the source code

```
public class DemoFragment extends BottomSheetDialogFragment {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    private BottomSheetBehavior.BottomSheetCallback mBottomSheetBehaviorCallback = new BottomSheetBehavior.BottomSheetCallback() {

        @Override
        public void onStateChanged(@NonNull View bottomSheet, int newState) {
            if (newState == BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_HIDDEN) {
                dismiss();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onSlide(@NonNull View bottomSheet, float slideOffset) {
        }
    };

    @Override
    public void setupDialog(Dialog dialog, int style) {
        super.setupDialog(dialog, style);
        View contentView = View.inflate(getContext(), R.layout.fragment_layout, null);
        dialog.setContentView(contentView);

        CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams =
                (CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams) ((View) contentView.getParent()).getLayoutParams();
        CoordinatorLayout.Behavior behavior = layoutParams.getBehavior();
        if (behavior != null && behavior instanceof BottomSheetBehavior) {
            ((BottomSheetBehavior) behavior).setBottomSheetCallback(mBottomSheetBehaviorCallback);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: I tried but I'm getting the same result. Could you paste the xml that you used please? Thanks

Comment: @Buntupana Updated the answer.Please try the solution & let me know the result.:)

Comment: sorry for the delay, I was abroad. I've copied and pasted you code and still it's not working. I tried with android O

Comment: Witch version of android did you try it @Don_Chakkappan??

Comment: No bounty no honey I guess...hahaha

Comment: @Buntupana I tried it with both Android M and Android O and seems working fine.If you post your full code I can help you.Now I don't have access to my Machine .Please don't underestimate people. :)